# Initialize RetryManager from EnterpriseLibraryContainer not working

Tags: c#, azure, enterprise-library

I used this code to initialize RetryManager from Enterprise Library:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.SqlAzure;
using Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling;

...

var manager = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<RetryManager>();
return manager.GetDefaultSqlConnectionRetryPolicy();
```

Now I updated Enterprise Library NuGet package to the newest version and there is no EnterpriseLibraryContainer anymore.

How can I initialize the RetryManager with the new Enterprise Manager? It must be thread safe because my code is executed on web server.

Comment: This is indeed frustrating.  I'm try to learn to use the logging block and have this same problem.  Hopefully MS can fix this up soon.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved it this way:

Remove all old NuGet packages and install only those two:

```
<package id="EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Data" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Add this code once in application:

```
var strategy = new FixedInterval("fixed", 10, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
var strategies = new List<RetryStrategy> {strategy};
var manager = new RetryManager(strategies, "fixed");
RetryManager.SetDefault(manager);
```

Then use new connection class from microsoft:

```
using (var connection = new ReliableSqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    ...
    command.ExecuteNonQueryWithRetry();
}
```

I also removed all configuration from Web.Config because it's in my code now.

Answer (score 1):

Can't use EnterpriseLibraryContainer anymore, have a look below whether this helps.

The config option is also still available:

Essentially you need the nuget package [EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Configuration](http://nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Configuration/6.0.1304.0)

Then you would need to update your web/app.config to something like:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="RetryPolicyConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Configuration.RetryPolicyConfigurationSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Configuration, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="typeRegistrationProvidersConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.TypeRegistrationProvidersConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</configSections>

<typeRegistrationProvidersConfiguration>
    <clear />
    <add sectionName="RetryPolicyConfiguration" name="RetryPolicyConfiguration" />
</typeRegistrationProvidersConfiguration>

<RetryPolicyConfiguration defaultRetryStrategy="Fixed Interval Retry Strategy"
                        defaultSqlConnectionRetryStrategy="Incremental Retry Strategy">
    <incremental name="Incremental Retry Strategy" retryIncrement="00:00:01" initialInterval="00:00:01" maxRetryCount="10" />
    <fixedInterval name="Fixed Interval Retry Strategy" retryInterval="00:00:01" maxRetryCount="10" />
    <exponentialBackoff name="Backoff Retry Strategy" minBackoff="00:00:01" maxBackoff="00:00:30"
                    deltaBackoff="00:00:10" maxRetryCount="10" firstFastRetry="false"/>
</RetryPolicyConfiguration>
```

If you get runtime errors like attribute "retryInterval" or "fastFirstRetry" is not a recognized attribute, try "initialInterval" and "firstFastRetry" instead, they have got renamed. For reference look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn199101%28v=pandp.60%29.aspx).

On code level you would need something like:

```
RetryPolicy retryPolicy;

try
{
    retryPolicy = RetryPolicyFactory.GetDefaultSqlConnectionRetryPolicy();
}
catch (NullReferenceException)
{
    throw new Exception("Unable to read transient fault handling behaviour from config, config section for TransientFaultHandling seems to be missing.");
}

return retryPolicy;
```

Hope this helps!